# Laravel working with JSON in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Hi I can't display JSON data from MySQL correctly, I need to access 'SKU' and 'qty' keys for each item in JSON individually. My code looks like this:

```html
// dummy data save

$order_items = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  array_push($order_items, array('SKU' => $item_sku, 'qty' => 1));
}
$order->items = $order_items;

$order->user_id = Auth::id();

$order->save();


// 'items' field in MySQL

[{"SKU": "CM10361", "qty": 1}, {"SKU": "CM10361", "qty": 1}, {"SKU": "CM10361", "qty": 1}, {"SKU": "CM10361", "qty": 1}, {"SKU": "CM10361", "qty": 1}]


// controller 

$orders = Order::with('orderAuthor')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();


// blade view code

{{ json_encode($orders->first()->items) }}


// blade output

  [{"SKU":"CM10361","qty":1},{"SKU":"CM10361","qty":1},{"SKU":"CM10361","qty":1},{"SKU":"CM10361","qty":1},{"SKU":"CM10361","qty":1}]
```

How can I access 'SKU' and 'qty' keys? Like `$items->SKU`?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to access it? at the HTML generated?

Comment: @JoseRojas in a blade view, I am looping with foreach through all $orders and I need to display a table with the SKU and qty key for each item (from the items JSON field) for each individual order from $orders

Answer (score 0):

At your view your have a collection, try to iterate the items through the method `each`, something like this:

```
$orders->each(function ($item, $key) {
  //here your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// controller 

$orders = Order::with('orderAuthor')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

//loop through results

foreach ($orders as $order)

{
  //now decode the json
  $decoded_order = json_decode($order);
  echo $sku      = $decoded_order->SKU;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are `json_encoding` the `items` object on your view (i.e. you're converting it to a string), when you actually want to access it as an array. I'm guessing that the `items` column is mutable (Laravel encodes/decodes it automatically), so if that's correct, I think you should just do:

```
@foreach ($orders->first()->items as $item)
    {{ $item['SKU'] }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the correct solution, finally

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
    @foreach ($order->items as $item)
         {{ $item['qty'] }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: your blade is not supposed to do these complex functions. Please take care and try to implement in your controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
//loop through results
@foreach ($orders as $orderKey=>$orderValue)
        $sku = $orderValue->SKU;
        $qty = $orderValue->qty;
        <tr>
                <td>{{$sku}}</td>
                <td>{{$qty}}</td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: {{ }} is equivalent to echo in Laravel, it's not necessary write the <?php

Comment: yes we can use @foreach for the foreach loop so that we dont need braces on starting and ending the loop and {{ }} for echoing the variable in Laravel.